# Laravel Convert SQL to Eloquent : order by a sum()

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm new to Eloquent and Laravel. I tried multiple syntaxes but I can't find a way to make it work. Here is the query I would like to convert :

```
SELECT category, SUM(amount) AS `total_cat` FROM expenses GROUP BY category ORDER BY `total_cat` DESC
```

And here's my Model for the "expenses" table :

```
class Expense extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['date', 'title', 'amount', 'category'];
}
```

The idea here is to get the sum of expenses for each category (the alias is not necessary). The query is working just fine in pure PHP. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be the solution, I haven't test but it seem fits the theory within the eloquent functions

```
Expense::select([
  'category',
  DB::raw('SUM(category) AS category_sum')
])
  ->groupBy('category')
  ->orderBy('total_cat', 'desc')
  ->get()
```

Comment: I get this : "Error
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found"

Comment: at the top of the file, include ```use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; ```

Comment: Hi @outik if you found this solution working, could you help me upvote my answer ~?

Comment: Will do ! I've changed a few things and it worked. Thank you again for helping

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for my initial problem:

```
Expense::select([
            'category',
            DB::raw('SUM(amount) AS total_cat') ])
            ->groupBy('category')
            ->orderBy('total_cat', 'desc')
            ->get();
```